# Kivy ids returns KeyError when assigning properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I tried to make a function in the `kivy 1.10.1` framework that would in theory make a group of a number of circles. It calculates the position of the center of the sphere using the parametic form with a given radius. In this case I want a circle for each letter of the alphabet. I make a new `Letter` widget for each letter but whenever it tries to add the position properties it returns a `KeyError: 'A'` with whichever key (which I thought I assigned in `self.add_widget(Letter(id=letter))`) I try to fetch.

### Main.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import math
import string


class Letter(Widget):
    pass


class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        theta = 0
        for letter in string.uppercase:
            coord_x = 100 * math.cos(theta)
            coord_y = 100 * math.sin(theta)

            self.add_widget(Letter(id=letter))
            self.ids[letter].center_x = coord_x
            self.ids[letter].center_y = coord_y

            theta += 360./float(len(string.uppercase))


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### Main.kv:

```py
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Letter>:
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.ids` only holds ids for widgets created in kv. You don't need it in Python because you already have a convenient reference to the widget:

```
l = Letter()
self.add_widget(l)
l.center_x = coord_x
l.center_y = coord_y
```

Comment: But to create `Letter()` 26 times I would have to write

`l1 = Letter()
l2 = Letter()
l3 = Letter()
...
l26 = Letter()`

What I tried to do was use a for loop to not have to declare 26 times.

Comment: @Bruno `l` is a local variable that keeps its reference so that in the loop it works, have you tried it? If you want to use those widgets then it stores the references in a list or dictionary